# What do edge colors mean in gitk?

Tags: git, version-control

I'm looking at git history and see various edge colors between commits: red, grey, blue, green, brown, etc.  What do these colors mean?  They seem quite random to me ...

Answer (score 13, accepted):

They're just so you can see better each branch evolution. The color itself doesn't mean much.

This gets more useful when you have lots of branches and merges. You can accompany the history more easily and, if you get lost where you are, you just find the edge with the color you were accompanying.

Comment: I wonder what the actual log is though? The colour sometimes changes from commit to commit with no obvious reason.